# How to assign multiple values in a single row of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to show the multiple values of particular item in a single row.

my dataframe df=

```
**|Item| assigned|**
|one | raju    |
|one | sanket  |
|two | vinay   |
|two | chandu  |
```

i want to show it it as

```
  **|Item| assigned       |**
    |one | raju ,sanket   |
    |two | vinay,chandu   |
```

Please let me know if anyone knows the above query . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

With this dataframe,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Item": "one one two two".split(), 
                   "assigned": "raju sanket vinay chandu".split()})
```

you can do

```py
df.groupby("Item").agg(",".join)
```

to get

```py
          assigned
Item
one    raju,sanket
two   vinay,chandu
```